# Is there a better notation for difference equations?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Difference equations are quite messy to deal with, esp. in constraint optimization with many time subscripts that invite mistakes. Is there a better notation? Something like Feynman diagrams for difference equations?

That would be quite amazing!

Best,

Hirek

Comment: It turns out that there isn't. But lag operators help to find the characteristic roots of these equations.